# Which communication is faster in React, Sibling-Parent-Sibling or Sibling-Store-Sibling?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm setting up communication between some sibling components in a React-Redux app.

What needs to be communicated is a single data value that really has no other purpose in the app outside of the child component that will display it.

It caused me to wonder if sending the data up to the parent and back down to the sibling is faster than dispatching an action and state change in the Redux store and letting the sibling receive the change that way.

My assumption is that for such a simple case just passing it up to the parent and back down is faster.

Certainly coding it through the parent will be faster than setting up the Redux actions.

Answer (score 0):

They're more or less the same, actually.

Passing the value either way (through Redux or through a parent) works the same -- React will virtually re-render the component tree, and if it's different, apply those changes to the DOM. To optimize your app, optimize your render times, rather than how you pass state around.

That said, doing it through Redux will most likely make your app more complex. You would have to make actions and reducers, and maintain that chunk of state in Redux. As you said it's a pretty local piece of information, it's probably better from an architectural standpoint to keep the state in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, both are equally same.

If you are using react-redux architecture then it is better to store the data in redux store as it not only provides the uniformity in your code but also makes your code scalable i.e. in case the same data is consumed in other component in future then there will not be any further steps involved.

I disagree with the point that redux makes the app complex.